# Update Published Apps in Android

Tags: android

Please how can I update my application after it has been launched on Google play store... Like if I add some features to my code how can that change the Google store app that I uploaded? Or did I need to unpublished it, change the code and then upload the application again?...

Comment: I think you have to dive into the basics: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/index.html and https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just submit the new APK using the release management, and don't forget to update the version number build.gradle

Comment: How can I do that with Eclipse

Comment: Have you launched an application yet on Google Play ? If not start reading the documentations how to do it.